# I'm trying to set up a marker inside of a QR code, but can't seem to get it to work

Tags: augmented-reality, qr-code, aframe

My client wants users/readers to be able to scan a QR code and be taken to the URL which has the AR experience. The same QR code should then be able to trigger the AFrame AR experience. I've dropped a marker inside of the QR code, but the camera is not recognizing the marker, even though I've referenced the marker pattern on the  entity.

```
<a-scene embedded arjs="detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;" vr-mode-ui='enabled: false;' renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;">
    <a-assets>
        <video id="video"
           preload="auto"
           src="testvideo.mp4"
           width="80" height="45" autoplay loop="true">
        </video>
    </a-assets>
    <a-marker-camera type="pattern" preset="custom" url="marker/marker.patt">
        <a-entity material="shader: flat; src: #video"
              geometry="primitive: plane; width: 80; height: 45;"
              position="0 0 0"
              scale=".05 .05 .05"
              rotation="45 0 0" play-on-window-click>
        </a-entity>
    </a-marker-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "dropped a marker inside of the QR code"? The QR code can be the marker itself if you add a frame to it and make it into a .patt file. You can see how it looks like with our platform [echoAR](https://www.echoar.xyz), we do the exact same thing there and the QR code looks like this (Your QR code should look similar): [image]